# SQL, join table on itself, order by created within a certain timespan

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have created a table with 4 columns and sorted on a big amount of dataID:

```
      ID           Type             Item                Date
   AU761201      12.37.47         121212322     2012-07-12 22:21:12
   AU761201      12.37.42         157856388     2012-05-12 23:21:05
   AU761201      12.37.42         164687782     2009-02-12 12:37:24
   BD871015      15.31.62         651564488     2007-10-25 15:12:23
   DU551023      19.35.14         048040408     2011-11-05 14:15:23
   DU551023      19.35.14         056505654     2011-11-04 23:23:23
      .              .                .                   .
      .              .                .                   .
      .              .                .                   .
      .              .                .                   .
      .              .                .                   .
```

What I want to do is to examine if any "ID" has bought two identical goods (same "Type" number) within the timespace of 24hours (DU 551023 in the example given)and sort out the IDs for which this applies.

My brain is currently bleeding from dealing with this som all help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For which database do you need this query for? You've mentioned two of them.

Answer (score 2):

For **MySQL**

```
SELECT T1.id
FROM TableName T1 INNER JOIN TableName T2 
   ON T1.id = T2.id AND T1.Type = T2.Type AND T1.Item > T2.Item
WHERE ABS(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(T1.date, T2.date))) <= 24
```

For **SQL Server**

```
SELECT T1.id
FROM TableName T1 INNER JOIN TableName T2 
   ON T1.id = T2.id AND T1.Type = T2.Type AND T1.Item > T2.Item
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(hh, T1.date, T2.date)) <= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an unique key in this table (something to distinguish to records). Suppose it is Item (otherwise change it in T1.Item != T2.Item).

```
select distinct T1.ID from Table T1, Table T2
where T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.Type = T2.Type 
  and Abs(T1.Date - T2.Date) < 1 and T1.Item != T2.Item
order by T1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

if its  SQL server then you can do it with exists

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID
FROM    MyTable AS a
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
             FROM   MyTable AS b
             WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
                    AND a.TYPE = b.Type
                    AND ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, a.Date, b.Date)) <= 24 )
ORDER BY a.ID
```

or you can use join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
FROM MyTable AS a
INNER JOIN MyTable AS b
ON a.ID=b.ID AND a.TYPE=b.Type
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF ( hour , a.Date , b.Date ))<=24
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with not finding function DATEDIFF or TIMEDIFF??